# How to play video with NSData?

Tags: iphone, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have NSData with 18 MB data in it.

I want to play video from this data.

Is there any method to play video from NSData.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a valid URL to play a video file. Where are you getting the NSData from? You must be getting it from a URL somewhere so just use that URL to do the playback.

Comment: I am fetching data from Database... Is there any way to play video with NSData?

Comment: What you'll have to do is write that data out to a file using the method writeToURL:atomically:, and then load the data using the URL. Be sure to delete the file when you no longer need it. I'm curious though, is there any reason you are storing a movie in a database? The usual pattern is to store the movie in a file and then store the URL in the database.

Comment: Steps: 
1. Dowload video from url and save to documents.
2. save local url to DB
3. Fetching Local url to get data
4. Then data to play video.

while using local url to play video did not play in device.
when I am using writToFile.

Comment: Just use the url you download the movie from.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html